# open-source/free borland together clone

Tags: open-source, uml, clone, borland-together

I was wondering if there is any open-source/free borland together clone to create uml diagrams like class diagrams, use case diagrams, sequence diagrams, etc.

Many thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168512/best-free-professional-looking-uml-tool , and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RISE Editor at www.RiseToBloome.com might have some of what you need.  But it depends on exactly what you're looking to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at what kind of UML models it can generate later.